# wordpress - use menus bar to manage different language of the same website

Tags: wordpress, menu

I am using wordpress for a website for my client and now they wanted different language for the same website.

I was thinking of creating 2 sets of menus in different languages and simply just change the menus when user want to change language.

Is there a way to do this?? Or how normally people do this??

Thanks for sharing :D

Answer (score 0):

You can switch your language using this plugin.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugins-language-switcher